# Angular CLI with PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to use the primeNg UI framework but it doesn't seem to work at all. I've followed the `GETSTARTED` section at their website. Everything is installed and imported but still it wont work. `<button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger"></button>` to try out a simple implementation but it wont do anything to the button

Comment: You don't get the styles?

Comment: Exactly, just a plain button like i wasn't even using the framework

Comment: Bad tagging, please improve the tagging!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. Only thing that worked for me was to copy all styles from the package into the project style file and use it.

Create a `css/scss` file in your project and copy the `primeui` styles into your file. Than use that file.

You can find the styles under

```
"yourProjectPath/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
```

Comment: Where do I find the style css file?

Comment: This seems like an ugly solution and should be a better way. Either way I tried this but I get plenty of errors when i paste the css code into my app.component.css file. Since its poorly formated I can't look through and try resolve the problem

Comment: I agree with you, this is not the best solution, but I solved it with it. About formatters, in your IDE it must be a formatter that automatically formats your code

Comment: I'm using sublime 3 and I cant find any auto formatter.

Comment: I just only suggest you that you can solve in that way

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

npm install :

```
npm install primeng --save
```

add primeng styles in your project **.angular-cli.json** file.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ]
```

add ButtonModule in your app module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
         ButtonModule
    ]
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Click"></button>
```

Comment: what does the dots stand for in the style? ´"styles": [
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ]´
Full path?

Comment: It defines the path where the node module files is defined.

Comment: This still doesn't change the button

Comment: after added styles in angular-cli.json stop the project then start and check the console error ??

Comment: Stop and Run the Project ? not reload because the angular-cli.json file not modified during running the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154525/discussion-between-chandru-and-amar).

Comment: any news please about this issue ?